# Memory leak issue due to EHCache

Tags: java, memory-leaks, ehcache

I am facing memory leak issue in my performance environment due to EhCache with below configuraiton:

```
<cache name="mycache"
            maxElementsInMemory="50000"
            eternal="false"
            timeToIdleSeconds="300"
            timeToLiveSeconds="0"
            overflowToDisk="false"
            diskPersistent="false"
            memoryStoreEvictionPolicy="LRU"
            />
```

I took the heap dump and trying to analyze the cause of leak using IBM Heap Analyzer. IBM Heap analyzer suspected memory leak with below information:

```
Leak suspect:   576,690,536 bytes (83.16 %) of Java heap is used by 128 instances of net/sf/ehcache/store/chm/SelectableConcurrentHashMap$Segment
Contains an instance) of the leak suspect: - org/springframework/orm/jpa/LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean holding 117,109,616 bytes at 0x1b6fb410

Total size: 576,690,536 bytes

Size:   528 bytes
```

My object (which is stored in ehcache) size is 88 bytes.

With this information I am not able to understand what can be the actual cause of memory leak in this case.

Are my objects not being flushed/removed from cache?
Is there any thing odd in my ehcache configuration?
If object is not being removed from cache, what can be the reason?

Any Idea?

Comment: I think this question is similar to yours: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8595492/ehcache-is-not-honoring-maxelementsinmemory I'm no expert of ehcache but did you try to update it to the latest version?

Answer (score 0):

Set `timeToLiveSeconds = <no of seconds>`. Should be greater than 0.